# Make ImageList added with VS form designer static

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to optimize my web form's loading, and one of the things that seems to consuming much time is this line of code in one of my control's `InitializeComponent` method:

```
upDownImageList.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer) 
    (resources.GetObject("upDownImageList.ImageStream")));
```

This same control's class is instantiated several times, so I believe it would help if I could make my `upDownImageList` static so that it has to be initialized only once (by the way, several image lists are used in other controls that are also instantiated more than once, so I think making them static as well would help a lot).

I could simply move this and every other lines that initialize my `upDownImageList` to an static constructor and make `upDownImageList` static manually, but since these lines are in the `InitializeComponent` section VS doesn't want me to edit manually, I'm afraid something might get messed up, such as VS thinking I'm not using the `ImageList` anymore and deleting my images from the resource.

But since I have no idea where my images are stored, I have no idea how to create and populate an `ImageList` with code and generate the corresponding resource files.

Do you have any experience with doing such thing? Should I just move the initializing lines to an static constructor and everything will be OK?